# kannada language is not supporting properly in TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I want to display Kannada text in a `tcpdf` file. Here is my code

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);    
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('PANCARD PDF');
$pdf->SetTitle('PANCARD ID - '.$temp_token);
$pdf->SetSubject('PANCARD PDF');
$pdf->SetKeywords('PANCARD PDF, PDF, example, test, guide');    
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));  
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED); 
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);    
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM); 

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) 
{
  require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php'); 
  $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}   
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);   
$pdf->SetFont('kozgopromedium', '', 11, '', true);   
$pdf->AddPage(); 
$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));    
$html = 'ಮುಂದಿನ ನಿಲ್ದಾಣ ಉದ್ಯಾನ ನಗರ';
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);   
$pdf->Output('kannada_lang.pdf', 'I');
```

I tried to use the following fonts, but i am not getting proper format

`1) kozgopromedium
2) kozminproregular
3) stsongstdlight.`

This is the output i am getting with space between the letters

[image]

below is my expected output

ಮುಂದಿನ ನಿಲ್ದಾಣ ಉದ್ಯಾನ ನಗರ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a non-embedded font the rendering is going to be somewhat dependent on your PDF reader software. With CJK languages, I've found it's pretty easy to just throw an embedded font in and that solves the problem.  This, as far as I'm aware, won't work for indic scripts like Kannada because of lack of support in TCPDF. (Using `Lohit-Kannada.ttf` resolves the spacing issue for instance, but the final text is not rendered correctly.)

Are you too far along in your project to use `mPDF` which has explicit support for Kannada? Here's a side by side comparison for what I was able to get out of TCPDF and mPDF (code for each follows below the image):

[image: Side by side rendering of text for TCPDF vs. mPDF]

TCPDF:

```
require_once('TCPDF/tcpdf.php');
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$font = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('Lohit-Kannada.ttf',  'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('PANCARD PDF');
$pdf->SetTitle('PANCARD ID - '.$temp_token);
$pdf->SetSubject('PANCARD PDF');
$pdf->SetKeywords('PANCARD PDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$l['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$l['a_meta_dir'] = 'ltr';
$l['a_meta_language'] = 'kn';
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
$pdf->SetFont($font, '', 11, '', true);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));
$html = 'ಮುಂದಿನ ನಿಲ್ದಾಣ ಉದ್ಯಾನ ನಗರ';
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
$pdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__).'/kannada_lang.pdf', 'F');
```

mPDF:

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
//I'm being a little lazy here and letting mPDF select the appropriate
//appropriate font.
$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
$mpdf->baseScript = 1;  // Use values in classes/ucdn.php  1 = LATIN
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<span style="text-shadow: 0.2 0.2 2 rgb(196,196,196);">'.
     'ಮುಂದಿನ ನಿಲ್ದಾಣ ಉದ್ಯಾನ ನಗರ</span>');
$mpdf->Output('kannada_mpdf_lang.pdf');
```

Comment: Can you please send me the link to download 'vendor/autoload.php'; or mpdf library. Bcz iam not able to find this.

Comment: I think this will work if i download autoload.php and check.

Comment: Oh, `vendor/autoload.php` is created by composer. The mPDF library's official installation method is with composer. https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/installation-v7-x.html  You can get composer from this link: https://getcomposer.org

Comment: thank your @EPB it is working , but how can preview this before download. ?

Comment: You mean to display it inline in the browser? If so, I think that should already be the default, but it may make sense to take a look at the `output` method's documentation. https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to render `next stop is the garden city` as text, not as HTML:

```
$pdf->SetFont('kozgopromedium', '', 11, true);
$pdf->AddPage();

// Cell($w, $h=0, $txt='', $border=0, $ln=0, $align='', $fill=0, $link='', $stretch=0, $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='M')
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'ಮುಂದಿನ ನಿಲ್ದಾಣ ಉದ್ಯಾನ ನಗರ', 1, 1, 'C', 0, '', 0);

$pdf->Output('kannada_lang.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Not working, it is giving the same output with space between the letters.